# Cosmological implications of String theory compactification?

Tags: cosmology, string-theory, space-expansion, cosmological-constant, compactification

Is the process of compactification of hidden dimensions in string theory equivalent to an increasing dilaton field?

Would one expect the compactification process to continue indefinitely?

Could the apparent cosmological expansion of space actually be due to hidden dimensions becoming more compact?

Cosmological distances measured with shrinking rulers will seem to increase.

Comment: Why would you think so?

Comment: As we live in a 4d world then the hidden dimensions of string theory must have become compact for some reason. Why shouldn’t they continue to get more compact? This would lead to the 4d Planck mass increasing together with all other masses.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, this isn't a stupid question.  There are several models of extra dimensions in classical General Relativity that shows that collapsing compact dimensions may be simultaneously accompanied with inflating external dimensions.  See for example the Kasner metric and its variations.  I'm myself interested by this possibility for our real world.

Comment: I have seen some papers looking at decompactification, the process where some dimensions "unroll".

Comment: @Cham I didn't mean to imply it was a "stupid" question, it's just a question that makes absolutely no attempt at explaining the thought process behind it. I think that if the asker expects answerers to give understandable answers, they should make *some* effort at writing a self-contained understandable question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm giving a toy model as a partial answer.

Consider a 5D spacetime, with an extra compact dimension.  I assume that the "external" 3D space section is isotropic and homogeneous everywhere.  The spacetime metric is thus
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
ds^2 = dt^2 - a^2(t) (dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2) - b^2(t) d\varphi^2,
\end{equation}
where $a(t)$ and $b(t)$ are cosmological scale factors, and the angular coordinate $\varphi$ is associated to the "internal" compact dimension.  Pluging this metric into the *empty* 5D Einstein equation $G_{AB} = 0$ (without any matter and without any 5D cosmological constant) give the scale factors:
\begin{align}\tag{2}
a(t) &= \alpha \, t^{\frac{1}{2}},
& b(t) &= \beta \, t^{- \frac{1}{2}},
\end{align}
where $\alpha \ne 0$ and $\beta \ne 0$ are arbitrary constants. In standard cosmology, the scale factor $a(t) \propto t^{1/2}$ describes a universe filled with random radiation.  So the solution above may be interpreted as a 3D "open" flat space filled with radiation, expanding in the standard way, while the "internal" compact dimension is collapsing with time.

This particular simple model could be generalized with many more extra-dimensions, with any "internal" topology, but the maths difficulty increases very fast!

Comment: Very interesting! What happens when you add a cosmological constant $\Lambda$?

Comment: Also if you add curvature $k=-1,0,1$.

Comment: Where is the 5D Einstein equation described in detail so I could do it myself?

Comment: @JohnEastmond, with $k \ne 0$ and $\Lambda_5 \ne 0$, we do get the same result, that is an empty 5D universe is similar to a 3D space filled with radiation, and a reduced cosmological constant: $\Lambda_4 = \frac{1}{2} \: \Lambda_5$.  There are tons of papers on this subject on arXiv.  For example: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0406279, https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0209261,https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0305066, https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0507107.

Comment: Thanks very much @Cham!